Do homogeneous systems with unique solutions cause linear systems to have a unique solution
I'm reviewing Linear Algebra using Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra textbook and a particular statement in the book seems unjustified to me.
So, firstly, the author recognizes this pattern that the solution set to a linear system can be expressed in the following form:
$\{\vec{p} + c_1\vec{r}_1 + ... + c_k\vec{r}_k\;|\;c_1,...,c_k\in\mathbb{R}\}$
To prove this theorem, the author uses two lemmas:
(1) For any linear system, the solution set of its homogeneous counterpart (where the coefficients remain the same but the constant terms become zero) can be written as the following:
$\{c_1\vec{r}_1 + ... + c_k\vec{r}_k\;|\;c_1,...,c_k\in\mathbb{R}\}$
(2) For any linear system and for any particular solution $\vec{p}$, the solution set equals
$\{\vec{p} + \vec{h}\;|\;\vec{h}\;\text{solves the homogeneous counterpart}\}$
So, for a linear system, if a particular solution does not exist, the solution set is just $\{\}$ (and (2) is vacuously true).
Now, suppose that a particular solution exists. Since the homogeneous counterpart always has a solution (the trivial solution which is the zero vector), there are two possibilities. If the homogeneous counterpart has a unique solution, $h = \vec{0}$ and the solution set for any linear system with the same coefficients (but, perhaps different constants on the RHS) will just be $\vec{p}$, a unique solution. If there are infinitely many homogeneous solutions, there will be infinitely solutions for the linear system.
Now, the author says that if a square matrix of coefficients of a homogeneous system has a unique solution, "the system has a unique solution for any constants on the right side" provided it has the same coefficients. The author provides the following example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$$
$x + 2y = 0, 3x + 4y = 0$
The above homogeneous system has a unique solution (the zero vector). Therefore, any linear system of the following form will have a unique solution:
$x + 2y = a, 3x + 4y = b$
This would be a valid line if the bold sentence a few paragraphs ago would be true: "Suppose that a particular solution exists". How do we know that a particular solution for a linear system with any constants on the right hand side will exist just because the square matrix of coefficients has a unique solution?

It is a consequence of the Rank-Nullity Theorem; basically, the square matrix will be invertible, so a solution always exists. Btw, your phrasing after the bold statement is not quite right: the existence of a solution depends on the system, so you can't start assuming "existence of a particular solution" for one system and then claim that this will mean that "the solution set for any linear system with the same coefficients will just be $p$". $p$ depends on the system.

@ArturoMagidin Got it thanks
